# How to send email via Excel when the value of cell is "Yes"

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table and a bit of macro. I wanted to automatically send email to a certain person when cell value == to "Yes".  Also I want to send the email only if the date is today.

Please see screenshot:

[image]
[Error Screenshot Sir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF0d1.png)

```
Private Sub cmdMove_Click()


    'Sub TestFile()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("J").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value) = "Yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next

            With OutMail
                .To = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet("Server").Range("I3").Value

                .Subject = "Reminder"

                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "Ryan").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                        "your account up to date"
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Send  'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the date value held?

Comment: The date is in column A, this macro will move all the data in the form and put it in Excel sheet ("Server").  After clicking the Move button (please see the screenshot) and if there is an alarm in our server, it will automatically send email to the email address I included there.

Comment: What format is it in? Is it a number or a string?

Comment: You can put a call to your sub in a `Worksheet_Change()` macro....Also is `Date` a cell? What do you mean send if the "date is today"?

Comment: Did you trying something like And Activesheet.Cells(cell.Row, "A") = Date

Comment: This file is designed to be used in a daily basis, For example Monday, I moved a data to excel sheet and then alarm says Yes, that would trigger the email. By next day Tuesday, I then moved another data, then the alarm says Yes, it will then trigger to send email but only for that day (Tuesday). The monday will not beincluded.

Comment: If you write code to send an email in an Excel VBA macro, that code is only going to run when you open that excel document. It's not going to automatically send it when Tuesday comes aruond. You probably also want to save a flag that tells you you sent the email. Otherwise when you open the document for the second time on Tuesday it'll send the emails again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following. Assumes Date is in  column A and is an actual Date and that can be compared with what the `Date` function returns. There is a fair bit of tidying up that could be done on this.

I would take note of @BruceWayne's comment regarding using a `Worksheet_Change` event. If you can decide which cell(s), or column, determine(s) the triggering of the sub e.g. if column H has a value that changes then test each condition and determine whether to send e-mail, then you can call this sub via that event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 8 Then 'e.g. for column H

       TestFile   'name of your sub

    End If

End Sub
```

Note I changed your LCase test as it could never be True with LCase = "Yes" and I used the typed function LCase$.

I have commented out the line for the body as this:

```
.Cells(cell.Row, "Ryan").Value
```

will throw an error. The "Ryan" part should be a column reference e.g. "A" or 1.
If the "Ryan" is a named range then you might use something like:

```
.Cells(cell.Row, .Range("Ryan").Column)
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestFile()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup

    With ActiveSheet

        For Each cell In .Columns("J").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

            If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
               LCase$(.Cells(cell.Row, "H")) = "yes" And .Cells(cell.Row, "A") = Date Then

                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                With OutMail

                    .To = wb.Worksheets("Server").Range("I3").Value

                    .Subject = "Reminder"

                  '  .Body = "Dear " & .Cells(cell.Row, "Ryan").Value _
                          & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                            "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                            "your account up to date"
                    'You can add files also like this
                    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                    .Display                     'Or use Display
                End With

                Set OutMail = Nothing

            End If
        Next cell

    End With

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Example of Worksheet_Event code in Sheet2 code window

[image: Sheet 2 event code]

And the associated standard module:

[image: Standard module code]

Comment: Sir I have to put that code within the cmdMove, correct?

Comment: It depends how you are going to fire this. If you want it to respond to a worksheet change event then this bit ...Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   goes in the worksheet code window associated where you want the event to fire from e.g. Worksheet1. Otherwise, it goes in a standard module and, if in response to a click then yes, as you have said. Do you want someone to have to press something for this to run?

Comment: Sir is it okay to send to you the file itself? I'm still having some hard time.I added a code in my Sheet as what you have in screenshot. The sub testfile I add it into a separate module.

Comment: I won't download files with code in I'm afraid for security reasons. There can be malicious code within macro enabled Excel files. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Does it run if you comment out the .Body line as '.Body ?

Comment: You can upload an .xlsx to a file share and share the code separately as a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I add the TestFile in module 1. The change event is in the Sheet("Server"). The cmdMove button also has a code. Sir I edit my main post, I added an image please see Sir. I don't know yet how to upload .xlsx file is there a way we can chat right here Sir.

Comment: With regards to the error. The TestFile sub must be declared as Public. Is it public in your version? And you don't need the word Call.

Comment: When I hit Move, Data moves from frmMain into my Sheet. however it doesn't send an email. I change the declaration of TestFile into Public now. TestFile is in module 1. How to call a testfile.?

Comment: You just write TestFile without Call TestFile

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 8 Then

TestFile

End If

End Sub

Comment: ^^Yes.  Have you got another sub somewhere that is moving data which sheet? And what is the name of the sheet with your Alarm table in? You should avoid using Activesheet and use the actual sheet name in question.

Comment: It's still not working Sir. I'm so much tired of this. If only I can send the file to you. But thanks, I know you're trying to help me. It's just that this is somthing really hard for me.

Comment: Hi Sir..Please click the link..No macro file Sir..https://ufile.io/n61f1

Comment: Just make sure you change this line If cell.Value Like "zhamepace@gmail.com"  back to the original  If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*"   Let me know if you understand it. Basically it works on whether you change column H to Yes (Alarm)

Comment: Hi Sir..it took me 5 days to respond.I went to our province last friday. But thank you so much..That really works Sir.I really appreciate you Sir.