# Google Spreadsheet opening (on 2nd top row) by the last cell edited using App Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Usually when you open Google sheets, it opens on 1st row - 1st cell by default , I want it to open on the last edited cell.

I could find code for navigating to last edited cell but I want something like where the last edited cell is shown on the top. Is there a way to implement this using App Script in Google Sheets?

Here is a picture of my description:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8xN1.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send email via Excel when the value of cell is "Yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920073/how-to-send-email-via-excel-when-the-value-of-cell-is-yes)

Comment: No.. Actually my question is usually when you open Google sheets, it opens on 1st row - 1st cell by default , I want it to open on the last edited cell (additionally show the last edited cell on the top (like the one in the picture))

Comment: I see. There are apps script functions for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609640/how-do-you-change-which-sheet-a-user-is-viewing-with-google-app-script  *However*, I recall similar question having been asked and the ultimate answer (albeit several years back) was the active cell view function is finicky and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Hi Byte, what exactly do you mean with "last edited cell"? The last row with any content, or actually the last changed cell?

Comment: I mean the last changed cell @jpp

Answer (score 0):

This can be a starting point to implement your solution.

```
function onOpen() {

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getRange(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRange'))
        .activate();
}

function onEdit(e) {

    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
        .setProperty('lastRange', e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() + '!' + e.range.getA1Notation());
}
```

In this implementation the whole last range will be "preserved", I mean, if your last edit was paste more than a cell, the *activation* will be on the full pasted range. The sheet will be preserved too.
Of course, one edited single cell will be recalled too.

I choose ScriptProperties but you can choose the best for your case (see [Class PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#methods))